# Trying to get property of non-object geolocation google API

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude, google-geolocation

I'm working in to get the latitude and longitude from google maps through the geolocation API. I have tried many times but always is showing this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\index3.php on line 16

The issue is that I'm not able to get the info from the `$url` so then, cannot get the latitude and longitude.

I changed my code and now it is, but still with no working.

```
<php

$address = urlencode('BTM 2nd Stage,Bengaluru,Karnataka,560076');
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&key=*************************************";


$json = file_get_contents($url); // I tried with the @ symbol and without it

$data=json_decode($json);

echo ($data->results[0]->geometry->location->lat);

?>
```

And also I used this one:

```
<php
$address = 'BTM 2nd Stage,Bengaluru,Karnataka,560076';
$encode = urlencode($address);
$key = "insert key here";
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$encode}&key={$key}";

$json = file_get_contents($url); // I tried with the @ symbol and without it
$data = json_decode($json);

echo "Latitud".($data->results[0]->geometry->location->lat);

?>
```

Without the @ symbol I have this error line

> **Warning**:  file_get_contents() has been disabled for security reasons in **[...][...]** on line **8**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - How to catch a 'Trying to get property of non-object' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714591/php-how-to-catch-a-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-error)

Comment: There is no line 16 ;)

Comment: Can you show what is in the `$data`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you aren't supposed to show everyone your app key.

Answer (score 0):

change **http** 
to **https** in your request url.

Answer (score 0):

As Abrucius, you msut use HTTPS or google will deny the request. You must also encode the address or else you will get a "Bad request" error.

```
<?php
$address = 'BTM 2nd Stage,Bengaluru,Karnataka,560076';
$encode = urlencode($address);
$key = "insert key here";
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$encode}&key={$key}";

$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json);

echo ($data->results[0]->geometry->location->lat);
```

Outputs: 12.9082396

Comment: Yeah I dit it, but it stills showing the same error... in the last one line

Comment: Next time may I suggest starting with such an obvious error in your OP? The error states specifically that the function has been disabled on a server level. Try using `curl` but if `file_get_contents` has been disabled, then it's likely curl has aswell. Find a different host..

Answer (score 0):

replace following code

```
    $address = 'BTM 2nd Stage,Bengaluru,Karnataka,560076';
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&key=AIzaSyDjWI3J9CNlANoB5PXNKq3nz1ZbYeOrNGE";
```

to

```
 $address = urlencode('BTM 2nd Stage,Bengaluru,Karnataka,560076');
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&key=AIzaSyDjWI3J9CNlANoB5PXNKq3nz1ZbYeOrNGE";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have provided `http` in the url, it should be `https`. Try below code that will help you. You have to use `urlencode()` because api will not allow space in the address, so you have to encode.

```
$address = 'BTM 2nd Stage,Bengaluru,Karnataka,560076';
$address = urlencode($address);

$url = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$address}&key=***************************";

$resp_json = file_get_contents($url);

$resp = json_decode($resp_json, true);
echo "<pre>";print_r($resp["results"][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']);
```

Try this code will work for sure

Comment: Did it, but it doesn't work. Even I removed the "at" symbol from the `file_get_contents` instruction, and shows me this: `file_get_contents() has been disabled for security reasons`

Comment: `Warning: file_get_contents() has been disabled for security reasons in [...][...]` you are getting error. Then you have to contact server provider to enable that

Answer (score 0):

WillParky93's answer seems to work fine for me. Maybe try following the next link to allow https wrappers:

[How to get file_get_contents() to work with HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/how-to-get-file-get-contents-to-work-with-https)

...or post the error you're getting so we can help you out

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue, I was getting this error because of a proxy configuration. I was testing into a network with a proxy configuration. So, the proxy is not allowing me to connect with the Google database. Then I tried to connect with a different network and it worked perfectly. Thank you guys for your aid!