# Trying to catch $xpath->evaluate in php

Tags: php, html, regex, dom, try-catch

I'm trying to catch a Trying to get property of non-object notice that occurs when my 
`$xpath->evaluate` doesn't find a matching object.

this is my code

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$sources = $xpath->evaluate("//img/@src"); # "/images/image.jpg"
$src = $sources[0]->value;
echo $src;
```

I've already tried putting `$sources = $xpath->evaluate("//img/@src");` inside a try and catch statement but since its not an exception error it doesn't work.

Also I've tried using

```
if ($sources) {
  $src = $sources[0]->value;
  echo $src;
}
```

this didn't work either.

Do you know what I can do catch the notice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - How to catch a 'Trying to get property of non-object' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714591/php-how-to-catch-a-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-error)

Comment: @ficuscr I've tried the solutions from this post but they didn't work.

Comment: Hi, "didn't work"? Not sure what you mean by that. The answer I shared I thought was clear. You can't catch an error. You can only catch an exception.

Comment: @ficuscr I mean the answer you shared didn't solve my problem. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `length` property of your result, which contains the count.

```
if ($sources->length > 0) {
    $src = $sources[0]->value;
    echo $src;
}
```

In addition to that: You can only catch exceptions. Warnings and errors aren't exceptions. If you want to catch them, you have to register your own error handler, which then throws an exception. In your case, this would also be possible, but it's always the better solution to completely avoid this kind of error.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that something is returned and the number of nodes returned...

```
if ($sources !== false && $sources->length > 0) {
  $src = $sources[0]->value;
  echo $src;
}
```

[`evaluate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php) may return a DOMNodeList, so the above code checks `length`.

Comment: I do get Undefined property: DOMNodeList::$count

Comment: `Returns a typed result if possible or a DOMNodeList containing all nodes...`, false only on error. Is check for `!== false` ideal? I'd be more explicit.

Comment: I do need to add an own count() function right? Because I get Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::count()

Comment: Try the alternative of using `length` (from http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php)

Comment: @ficuscr, evaluate only returns a typed result if you do something like `evaluate("count(//img/@src)")` which they aren't doing, false is only returned 'If the expression is malformed or the contextnode is invalid'.

Comment: Nigel, agreed. I had to stop and test that. Was perceiving issue as probably evoking length on a string.